# Using ByteBuddy with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: java, android, android-annotations, byte-buddy

I'm trying to use [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) in my AndroidAnnotations-based project.

I have a class `MyService` that is an `EBean` (AA) with some injected dependencies:

```
@EBean
public class MyService {

    @Bean
    SomeRepository repo;

    @Log
    public void doSomething() { //do something that uses "repo" }

}
```

I want log something before execute any method of this class annotated with `@Log`.

I can get new instance of `MyService` this way:

```
MyService service = MyService_.getInstance(context); //MyService_ is generated by AndroidAnnotations
```

and all `@Bean` dependencies are injected. Everything ok.

Now, using ByteBuddy, I need create a dynamic subclass to intercept annotated methods:

```
  Class<? extends MyService> dynamic = byteBuddy
                .subclass(MyService_.class)
                .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Log.class))
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new LogInterceptor()))
                .make()
                .load(getClassLoader(), new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy(getDir()))
                .getLoaded();
```

I need subclass `MyService_` instead of `MyService` beacuse it uses the `Context` to inject dependencies. If I would subclass `MyService`, `repo` will be always `null`.

The problem is that auto-generated class `MyService_` is `final`, so I can't subclass it. `getInstance` method is static and constructor is private but I could obtain an instance by reflection so it is not a problem.

Any idea? Has anybody integrated ByteBuddy with AndroidAnnotations?

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Byte Buddy can redefine classes instead of subclassing them. If you manage to hook into the class loading, you might be able to do that. As far as I know, Android Annotations are created at compile time. The easiest would be to unfinalize the classes.